# How can I get last N records from a stream using Kafka KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Suppose I have a stream that contains stock prices. Each record consists of

- ticker
- price

e.g.

- AAPL,102.23
- FB,23.34
- AAPL,101.99
- AMZN,45.43
- ...

I need to fetch last 60 price records for AAPL. I don't want to use time windows - just last 60 records.

Comment: I don't think ksql can do this, but kafkacat can

Answer (score 1):

You can build a table that tracks the last 60 prices, per-ticker, using something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE RECENT_PRICES AS 
  SELECT
    tickerId,
    LATEST_BY_OFFSET(price, 60) AS PRICES
  FROM TICKS
  GROUP BY tickerId;
```

[LATEST_BY_OFFSET docs](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/aggregate-functions/#latest_by_offset).

The `PRICES` column will be an `ARRAY<DECIMAL(?, ?)>` holding the latest 60 prices.

Note: this is latest *by offset*, not by timestamp. So out-of-order data may cause problems.